# NPM: npm update is not changing the version in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, npm, semantic-versioning

I have an `express` project. One of the dependencies is updating in `package-lock.json` and installing the new version, but the one in `package.json` is not changing.

**package.json**

```
"x-dependency": "^1.73.0",
```

**package-lock.json**

```
"x-dependency": {
  "version": "1.73.1",
  "resolved": "",
  "integrity": "",
  "requires": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
},
```

**Notes:**

This is a custom dependency that I manage in my registry.

NPM version is 6.14.8

Both files have the same permissions.

Comment: Please add an example of two such version numbers. It would make it much clearer.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does, which means it should not cause an issue. But reading your question again, I'm not sure why package.json would remain unchanged. Though as said it should not prevent newer minor versions from being installed.

Comment: What npm version are you using?

Comment: @Boaz yes the issue is that the installation is working but the file is not updating. I'm using NPM 6.14.8

Comment: That is a recent version. Have you compared the permissions of the `package.json`and `package-lock.json` files? Maybe there's a difference between them? Please add this information and the npm version number to the body of the question.

Comment: @Boaz they both have the same permissions

Comment: Perhaps an issue with the `package.json` of the `x-dependency` itself? Consider including the relevant parts from that file too, if possible.

Comment: @Boaz I can share specific attributes if needed